# How can I trigger C# Console Application with gitlab ci yaml?

Tags: c#, gitlab, yaml, jobs

I have a console application which merges tables. I want this application to be run ever day (not manually). I use gitlab (or C# code) to trigger every day same hour.

My Project path:

> D:\DIGI\SSHKeyLastUpdatedVersionRepo\Utils\MergeTable\MergeTable.sln

How can I execute this application every day at same hour with GitLab CI/CD?

Comment: Where do you want this application to run? The path you provided is local, so should it run locally? Use a Cronjob/Scheduled Task. I'm certain that using CI is the wrong approach for running things by a timed schedule.

Comment: not local but  I think to execute a program we should know the path of program.

Comment: But you will not be able to tell CI to execute an application by specifying a local path (like D:\...).

Comment: I guess I know wrong. Can you give an small example for me? I really need it.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.hangfire.io/) out